# npm start run in wrong path

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start

First of all i'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and i create a node.js project under  `/home/user/project_folder`.

When i type `npm start /home/user/project_folder/`, i get this error:

> npm ERR! node v4.6.1 
>   npm ERR! npm  v4.0.2 
>   npm ERR! path /home/user/package.json 
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT 
>   npm ERR! errno -2 
>   no such file or dir..

Am'i doing it wrong? did i forget something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm doesn't take the path as an argument.

What you want is:

```
cd /home/user/project_folder && npm start
```

You can put it in a script, e.g. save this as `/home/user/project_folder/run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/user/project_folder && npm start
```

Change permissions with:

```
chmod a+x /home/user/project_folder/run.sh
```

And run it with just:

```
/home/user/project_folder/run.sh
```

Or without changing permissions:

```
sh /home/user/project_folder/run.sh
```

Comment: yes in that work it works with the terminal but when i launch it from a scipt it doesnt work

Comment: i created a service in /etc/init/ to launch the service with that path, i did it before and it worked fine, but now i get this error. it seems like npm start doesnt look for the right path.

Comment: what i did to fix it is creating a new user and change the project folder under the new user home directory and it worked. So i still don't know why it happened. but your solution is good too, i tested it and it worked too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `npm start` you don't need to specify the file path. You have to be on the directory of your project `cd project_directory` and there run `npm start`. Also make sure that in your package json, you have specified in the `"start"` property, the file to start.

Comment: yes i know, but i need to launch the server from a shell script